# Swift UIButton Set Title from Plist Key

Tags: swift, uibutton, plist, title

I'm trying to set the title of a button from a key value in my plist file in *Swift.* This is what I got with my button declaration:

```
@IBOutlet var answerButton_1: UIButton!

 answerButton_1.setTitle(questionsArray.objectAtIndex(0).objectForKey("A"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

and the error I get is this:

**'AnyObject' is not identical to 'String'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast to `NSDictionary` and `String` because Swift does not know what type an array element is.

```
let question = questionsArray.firstObject as NSDictionary
let title = question.objectForKey("A") as String
button.setTitle(title forState:.Normal)
```

You could still do this on one line (with brackets) but it is more readable if you split it up as above.

Comment: Great, thanks Mundi. It works now. For the one-liner I did this: answerButton_1.setTitle(questionsArray[0].objectForKey("A") as? String, forState: UIControlState.Normal)     As you mentioned your suggestion makes it more readable, but both methods work